# My custom admin grid isn't showing?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

I've been fighting with a problem for the last couple of days (I'm new to M2), so I hope you can help me further in this task to find a solution. I've been following this guide: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html

My **di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="coolrunner_shipping_labels_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">CoolRunner\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Labels\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="CoolRunner\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Labels\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">coolrunner_shipping_labels</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">CoolRunner\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Labels</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

My **controller (Index.php)**

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory = false;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Labels')));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

My **Layout file**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="coolrunner_shipping_labels_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My **ui_component file**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">coolrunner_shipping_labels_listing.coolrunner_shipping_labels_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">coolrunner_shipping_labels_listing.coolrunner_shipping_labels_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Post</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">coolrunner_shipping_labels_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="post_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="package_number">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pakkenummer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Oprettet</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

The result is just a blank page with the title "Labels". It doesn't add any grid to the page? Do you have any idea where the problem could be? I hope you guys can help me with this.

[image: Result page]

Answer (score 0):

```
   <dataSource name="coolrunner_shipping_labels_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">coolrunner_shipping_labels_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

Everything looks ok except`<dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">`

Comment: Hi @sudo55 , i changed my dataSource in ui_component to that you send, but still get same result. You know howcome? It doesnt even show an empty table. Its just blank.

Comment: okay realod the page, open the network in inspect and see  if there is error?

Comment: No errors in network tab :/ Tell me if there is any additionel information you need :)

Comment: And if try using the other method i get told its deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

My route was set wrong.